# Type hinting for a Callable that supports subclasses?

Tags: python, python-typing

I would like to type-hint a method that may receive a Callable that operates on A or sub-classes of A:

```
def do(f: Callable[[A], None])
```

I've also tried:

```
def do(f: Callable[[typing.Type[A]], None])
```

A full dummy example looks like this:

```
class A:
    n = 1

class B(A):
    n = 2

def something_a(x: A):
    print(x.n)

def something_b(x: B):
    print(x.n)

def do(f: Callable[[A], None]):
    f(B())

do(something_a)  # ok
do(something_b)  # PyCharm type check warnning
```

Comment: PyCharm is correct to warn here. Since ``do`` only takes ``f: (A) -> None`` functions, it could merely call ``f(A())`` without violating its contract to ``f``. ``something_a`` works with that, ``something_b`` does not (it requires "at least" a ``B``). You might want to read up on co- and contravariance.

Comment: I think that `f(B())` is perfectly valid (not violating `Callable[[A], None]`). I do see your point however that if I allow `do` to accept `something_b`, than it could pass it an `A`, which could "break" `something_b`'s contract. Thanks, Missed that.

Comment: Yes, the code itself as-is is valid, but ``do`` actually takes a ``f: (B) -> None``.

Answer (score 3):

As MisterMiyagi pointed out -
The type check warning is correct.

`B` inherits from `A`, so `something_a(x: A)` can accept both `A` and `B`, whereas `something_b(x: B)` can only accept `B`. (**covariance**)

If we pass `something_b(x: B)` to `do(f: Callable[[A], None])`, we allow `something_b(x: B)` to accept an `A` - which it can't. So `something_b(x: B)` can't substitute `something_a(x: A)`. On the other hand passing `something_a(x: A)` to a function that expects a `Callable[[B], None]` would've been okay. (**contravariance**)

**What to do?** - use Generics

```
AType = TypeVar('AType', bound=A)

def do_fixed(f: Callable[[AType], None]):
    pass

do_fixed(something_a)  # ok
do_fixed(something_b)  # ok
```

While we do get a warning for passing other type of callable:

```
class C:  # not derived from A
    n = 1

def something_c(x: C):
    print(x.n)

do_fixed(something_c)  # type check warning
```

But we still need to make sure we're not passing `A` to `something_b`, which can be achieved by:

```
def do_safer(f: Callable[[AType], None], v: AType):
    f(v)
    
do_safer(something_a, A())  # ok
do_safer(something_a, B())  # ok
do_safer(something_b, A())  # type check warning
do_safer(something_b, B())  # ok
```